# Does this construction of two sets contain a paradox?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose two sets {$X, Y$} are constructed according to the following rules:

$\forall x \subseteq X$ such that $|x|$ is finite, $x \in X$

$\forall y \subseteq Y$ such that $|y|$ is finite, $y \in Y$

$\forall x \subseteq X$ such that $|x|$ is infinite, $x \in Y$

$\forall y \subseteq Y$ such that $|y|$ is infinite, $y \in X$

and neither set contains any "atomic" elements. Then is there anything in the construction that renders the existence of the sets defined impossible?

Comment: If $X$ is finite then you have $X \in X$, which is typically not okay.

Comment: Could you explain why (or point me in the direction of an explanation)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox

Comment: The Axiom of Foundation doesn’t hold for such sets.

Comment: @Randall: Actually Cantor's theorem is far more relevant here.

Comment: @Randall Russell's paradox in no way prohibits sets containing themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed impossible, even without resorting to the Axiom of Foundation.

Since every subset of $X$ is finite or infinite, $\mathcal P(X)\subseteq X\cup Y$. And likewise for $\mathcal P(Y)$.

But now let's see what are the options:

1. $X$ is finite. Well, in that case $\mathcal P(X)=X$ by the first condition, and that is impossible.
2. $X$ is infinite. That means $Y$ is also infinite. Let $x$ be an infinite subset of $X$, then $x\in Y$, but since $Y$ is infinite $y_x=Y\setminus\{x\}$ is an infinite subset of $Y$, $y_x\in X$. Therefore the function: $$F(x)=\begin{cases} x & x\text{ is finite,}\\ y_x & x\text{ is infinite}\end{cases}$$ is an injection from $\mathcal P(X)$ into $X$.

In any case we get an injection from $\mathcal P(X)$ into $X$. Therefore a contradiction to Cantor's theorem.

---

Of course, the situation is different if you're working with non-standard set theories such as Quine's New Foundation. If the set of all sets exists, then taking $X=Y=\{x\mid x\text{ is a set}\}$ works.